# Whm login issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, whm

I have created an aws instance and installed a Cpanel server. after I start stopped my instance the public IP address has changed and i am not able to login by typing whmlogin command or 2087?
Is there a way to log in to whm or change the public IP to new one?

Comment: Do you have access to the AWS console?  How are you defining the host to connect to?  Are you using an IP address to connect or did you update DNS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.